# Modal NSAlert from NSOperation

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, nsoperation, nsalert

I have a time consuming process which runs with an NSOperation.
I now need user's choice to choose between different subprocesses.
I need to stop the process until the user respond to the question.

How can I do this from an NSOperation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should just be a matter of creating an NSAlert and calling `runModal` on it, making sure you're on the main thread. Have you tried that?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps in the method where you are creating the NSAlert, you can have assert([NSThread isMainThread]) at the top of the method and I think that this will assure that this method get executed on the main thread. I hope this helps!